# Is it possible to install 4GB (4X1GB chips) on a Gateway e6300?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I installed 4 1GB RAM chips in a used Gateway e6300, expecting a functional 4GB machine.  The system beeped and failed to boot.  So I tried taking out two of the chips - Two of the slots have white tabs (i.e., that hold the chip in place) at the sides and the other two have black tabs; so I left a chip in each white-tabbed slot and took the chips out of the black-tabbed slots.  (The same-color-tabbed slots are not next to each other - i.e., they alternate.)  The system booted with this configuration, with the expected 2GB of RAM.  (The 4 chips are all the same: 1GB DDDR2-533 PC2-4200 Non-ECC, ...)

After a bit of searching, finding the user guide and documentation of the specs (http://www.cnet.com/products/gateway-e-6300/specs/), I found no indication of the max RAM this system is supposed to support.  (It may be out there, but I didn't find it.)

So, my questions are:  How much maximum RAM should the e6300 support?  And if it does support 4GB, should my original 4X1GB configuration have worked (implying that the problem was a defective slot/motherboard, incorrect installation, or bad chip(s))?  If this config. doesn't work but 4GB is supported, what's the configuration for 4GB - Is it 2X2GB?

Answer (score 0):

Your gateway supports maximum of upto 4 GB RAM, 4X1 GB, Either your are not connecting it properly or chips are bad try connecting the RAM after cleaning by an eraser.

> Gateway E-6300 Series Computer Memory. The Gateway E-6300 Series Computer takes the PC2-5300 DDR2 SDRAM DIMM 240pin memory Memory Type, and comes installed with 1GB(Removable) of Memory. You can upgrade your Gateway E-6300 Series Computer to up to a maximum memory capacity of 4GB Memory, the system has 4Sockets(2 banks of 2) to install Memory, already with 1GB(Removable) standard memory installed. For best E-6300 Series Computer performance use the maximum amount of allowed Memory per slot for your Computer. [source](http://www.memorystock.com/memory/GatewayE6300Series.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you put 2 GB 240-pin DIMMs in each of the 4 memory sockets, you can use 8 GB. I am using 6 GB (2x2 GB and 2x1 GB) and it is working fine.

Make sure that both 2 GB DIMMs are in the white-colored slots and both 1 GB DIMMs are in the black-colored slots.

The reason your system was beeping because the memory stick was most likely loose in the socket.